# why after applying my function to the array it returns the same array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, compare, return-value

I'm looping over an array with my function compare to get the max number of temperature from the array but there was no any changes after applying the function to the array temperature.

```js
let temperature = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "error"];

function compare(temperature) {
  let i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
if (typeof temperature[i] === "string") temperature.splice(i, 1);
  }

  for (let k = i + 1; k < temperature.length; k++) {
if (temperature[i] < temperature[k]) Array.splice(i, 1);
else if (temperature[i] > temperature[k]) Array.splice(k, 1);
  }
  return temperature;
}

console.log(temperature);
```

Comment: Arrays don't have a property `lneghth`. You're not calling the function.

Comment: @Ali I added an answer. I hope it helps as per the problem statement you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a single line of code by using `Math.max()` on array.

**Working Demo :**

```js
// Input array
let temperature = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "error"];

// Math.max() to get maximum number element from an array.
const maxTemp = Math.max(...temperature.filter(elem => typeof elem !== 'string'));

// Result
console.log(maxTemp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out!

```
let temperature = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "error"];

function compare(temperature) {
    let i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < temperature.length; i++) {
        if (typeof temperature[i] === "string") 
            temperature.splice(i, 1);
    }

    for (let k = i + 1; k < temperature.length; k++) {
        if (temperature[i] < temperature[k]) 
            Array.splice(i, 1);

        else if (temperature[i] > temperature[k]) 
            Array.splice(k, 1);
    }
    return temperature;
}

console.log(compare(temperature));
```